# Tomcat V7.0 server out of memory error in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7, out-of-memory

I am trying to run two separate projects from my tomcat server on eclipse. It will run each individually but when I try to run them both at the same time, it will not start and it prints the following on the console:

```
    Exception in thread "main" 
    Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

I have done some experimenting by increasing my heap by starting eclipse with :

```
    eclipse.exe -vmargs -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
```

I have increased the values but still no luck. I have also tried creating a new server and I still get the same error. The interesting part is that I am working with team with the exact same code and neither member is having this problem. One member has exactly the same computer with the same ram and all specs, so I don't believe that I am truly running out of memory. Does anyone know of any other possible solutions to this problem?

-Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

If Tomcat is running out memory, you need to give *Tomcat* more memory, not Eclipse.  From the Run menu, open the Run Configurations and modify the VM arguments for your Tomcat launch.